# Where to ask for cheapest product meeting a certain condition?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

I want to ask the question: **What is the cheapest U.S. (consumer market) passenger car capable of self-driving in heavy traffic (i.e. bumper-to-bumper traffic under 30 mph on the highway)?**

Google is useless for this because it is not capable of discerning the concept of "cheapest" or "capable of self-driving in heavy traffic".

The question is perfect for a crowd-sourced Q&A site since the odds are good that each subsequent answer will be closer to correct than the previous, with a high degree of confidence being given when no one can improve the answer.

Where can I ask this question?

Comment: Science fiction & fantasy?

Answer (score 7):

> The question is perfect for a crowd-sourced Q&A site

No, it is not. It is a [shopping request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) which is a terrible fit for Q&A. Here a quote of the founder of the SE network of sites:

> the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year

And that is bad. We want to create a knowledge base that isn't time-sensitive. It is a waste of hard work. What about *What is the best phone?* Every day there is a new best phone.

This kind of questions don't contribute to the long term goals of the site.

So where can you ask such questions? Not here at least.

Comment: `terrible fit for Q&A` Keep in mind there are multiple sites dedicated to shopping requests (hardware/software recommendations). It's not inherently bad, it's just... really hard.

Comment: @enderland Good point, but the OP is better ask on the site meta before I think. As some site flag such question as offtopic on sigh for the reason Patrick's told. An example on Serverfault for an actual close reason; *Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.*

Comment: @yagmoth555 That's similar to Stack Overflow's close message, but I think I like it better. I might suggest that we change our close message...

Answer (score 2):

It might be perfect for a Q/A site (for varying definitions of "perfect") but unfortunately there is not any existing site on the Stack Exchange network where a question like this would fit.

You might have luck in the [mechanics.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) but I am not sure.